# UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification not Firing when Swiping to another element

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility

I am using `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` and `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification` in my app. According to [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Accessibility/AccessibilityfromtheViewControllersPerspective.html), the notification should be posted either when the announcement finishes successfully or it does not (i.e. the user swipes to another element on the screen).

`UIAccessibilityAnnouncementDidFinishNotification` expects an `NSNotification dictionary` as a parameter from which you can determine the value spoken and whether or not the speaking has completed uninterrupted. Speaking may become interrupted if the `VoiceOver` user performs the stop speech gesture or swipes to another element before the announcement finishes.

It works fine if the announcement finishes, but if I swipe or tap the screen before it finishes, no notification is posted. Any thoughts on why this might be? Could it be a bug? If so, any suggestions on workarounds? I have text coming in that needs to be read sequentially so am using this to synchronize. Even if I could somehow reset my speaking flag to 0 when the user taps the screen/does anything, that would be great.

Comment: Can I see your code? I can't even get UIAccessibilityInvertColorsStatusDidChangeNotification to work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom view and that custom view needs to implement the protocol `UIAccessibilityFocus`

```
- (void)accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused
- (void)accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus
- (BOOL)accessibilityElementIsFocused
```

Comment: Interesting.  With a little swizzling one doesn't need to have a custom view.  Seems to work great.

Comment: The other option is to add a category / extension to UIView  or a protocol extension (if you are using swift). The only catch is that it will apply to all UIView if you don't use a subclass. Protocol extensions / category will still need a subclass to be specific.